# Thought process behind vector valued functions and parameterisation

Tags: functions, vectors, intuition, parametrization

Can someone please confirm whether my intuitive notions behind what vector-valued functions and parameterisation is correct. Below are some questions.

Are vector-valued functions like functions of a single variable with domain of real values and range of vectors in an $n$-dimensional space? Does the vector-valued function involve a formula for a position vector which traces out a curve when the range of input values varies?

Do we use parameterisation's to describe curves which cannot be expressed as functions like $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(y)$? How are vector-valued functions and parameterisation's related?

I'm studying physics and these are some math preliminary  topics for when I study motion of point Particles,  dynamics and conservation laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are vector-valued functions like functions of a single variable with
>   domain of real values and range of vectors in an n-dimensional space?

Yes, but a vector-valued function can have any number of variables, e.g., ${\bf v}(r, s, t, w)$.

> Does the vector-valued function involve a formula for a position
>   vector which traces out a curve when the range of input values varies?

Yes, but again, there may be several variables involved.  For a continuous vector-valued function the "tip of the vector" in general sweeps out a line, surface, volume, etc., depending upon the number of variables.

> Do we use parameterisation's to describe curves which cannot be
>   expressed as functions like y=f(x) and x=g(y)? How are vector-valued
>   functions and parameterisation's related?  What are parametric equation and are they similar to vector valued functions in any way?

One can parameterize a vector-valued function as ${\bf v} = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k) = (f_1(t), f_2(t), \ldots, f_k(t))$.

Comment: I was asking regarding parametric equations, curves and their traces and how vector valued functions fit in with them. Apologies if I'm unclear. That's why I'm trying to make sense of it by asking.

Comment: It is clear you were asking "regarding" parametric equations, but it is not clear *what* you were asking.

Comment: Let me rephrase and ask what parametric equations are and if they are similar to vector valued function's in any way.